# JS, Vue.js определение формы

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Допустим у меня есть многомерный массив с новостями который приходит с сервера:

```
news = [
    0 => [
        'title' => 'title0',
        'content' => 'content0',
        'published' => 'published',
        ...
    ],
    ...
]
```

Во Vue компоненте я его перебираю и отображаю каждую новость в форме (убрал много ненужный тегов не дающих смысловую нагрузку):

```
<div v-for="article in news">
    <form @submit.prevent="addNews">
        <input type="text" name="title" :value="article['title']">
        <input type="text" name="content" :value="article['content']">
        <input type="text" name="published" :value="article['published']">
        <button type="submit">Добавить изменённую новость</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Сам вопрос: как мне в методе `addNews` (который вызывается из формы при нажатии кнопки) определить именно ту форму в которой кнопка была нажата? 
Например из этой формы определить заголовок и дальнейшее взаимодействие с ним.

Если форма одна, я бы дал каждому полю `v-model`, а в моём случае `v-model` будут повторяться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался... Например чтобы получить заголовок из формы:

```
addNews(submitEvent) {
    console.log(submitEvent.target.elements.title.value)
}
```

Comment: Кажется это не очень хорошее решение, лучше передать параметр в обработчик, примерно так: `@submit="addNews(article)"`

Comment: @diraria, Не понял вашу мысль, можно чуть поподробнее)